# How do “Send Alerts for These changes” works, inside “Alert Me”

Tags: 2013, development, publishing-site, alert, publishing-page

I have a publishing site collection using the enterprise wiki, and then I have configured the outgoing email. Currently when users click on “Page Option  Alert Me” they will get the following dialog:-

[image]

But I got confused on the options available for the “Send Alerts for These Changes” mean. Does “Anything changes” mean anything changed for the selected page or anything changes for the current site ? and regarding the other three options are they specific to certain page or they are general settings?

Answer (score 1):

This means the changes of the object. In your case it is the single page. You can create alerts for List/Library or for single element.

Comment: so what does "someone else changes a document" means ? i mean which document there are referring to, i document i create an alert on  ?

Comment: Yes, the document for which you have created alert. Or all items in List, if you have created an alert for list.

Comment: aha so the first option will send alerts even if i changed the page, while the other options is someone else ..